# Missing library to ingest data into Azure Data Explorer with PySpark

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to ingest data into Azure Data Explorer through PySpark with PyCharm IDE. However, I am having a lot of problems related to missing libraries when running my code.

According to [Azure Data Explorer connector's page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark), I need to install the [connector's jar](https://jarcasting.com/artifacts/com.microsoft.azure.kusto/kusto-spark_2.4_2.11/) and the two dependencies jar [kusto-ingest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.kusto/kusto-ingest) and [kusto-data](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.kusto/kusto-data).

After download all these 3 jar's and importing them to PySpark, I can't proceed with my data ingestion, it keeps returning me missing library errors. The first one is the azure-storage lib, then I've installed and imported the jar, it asks for adal4j lib, I do the same and it asks oauth2 lib, then json lib, azure-client-authentication lib, javax mail lib, and so on.

I've installed more than 10 jars and I still can't run this ingestion. Am I doing something wrong?

My PySpark version is 2.4. You can see my code below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .appName("Teste") \
    .config('spark.jars', 'kusto-spark_2.4_2.11-2.5.2.jar,kusto-data-2.4.1.jar,kusto-ingest-2.4.1.jar,azure-storage-8.3.0.jar,json-20180813.jar,adal4j-1.6.5.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()

# loading a test csv file
df = spark.read.csv('MOCK_DATA.csv', header=True, sep=',')

df.write.format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource")\
  .option("kustoCluster", "myclustername")\
  .option("kustoDatabase", "mydatabase")\
  .option("kustoTable", "mytable")\
  .option("kustoAadAppId", "myappid")\
  .option("kustoAadAppSecret", "mysecret")\
  .option("kustoAadAuthorityID", "myautorityid")\
  .mode("Append")\
  .save()
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with a non-maven installation you need to use a JAR with all the dependencies.
You can take it from the github releases:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/releases
or build yourself if its missing from the specific version by cloning the repo and running
mvn assembly:single

Comment: Hi Ohad Bitton, thank you so much for your answer. I'm sorry for the late response, I really did not had time to test it before. I have downloaded the latest release source and ran the command mvn assembly:single. The build has successfully completed but the generated JAR returned the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource" when running a read table command. I've tested it with Spark 2.4.0, 2.4.2, 2.4.3 and 2.4.4. The same code works with a JAR published on the repo for Spark 3.0. However I need it working for Spark 2.4.

Comment: hi, sorry too for late response - this seems like an installation issue as 2.4 JAR and 3.0 JAR are created the same way
please try with latest version JAR again and make sure that is the only loaded JAR that contains the library

Comment: Also if you do it yourself - make sure that the resulted JAR contains the connector

Comment: I've got success to build a working JAR file using a different computer, thank you!